# How to trim part of a string in php?

Tags: php, string

I want to trim a String. Here is my code:

```
$base2 = chop($base,"www.");
```

$base contains www.example.com
I want it to remove the www.

I thought that this would work. I think I have the latest PHP version.

Answer (score 2):

Use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php):

`$base2 = str_replace('www.', '', $base);`

This replaces `www.` with nothing, so it gets deleted.

Answer (score 2):

[`chop`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chop.php) is an alias for [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php), i.e. it only removes characters from the end of the string (so e.g. `chop($base,".com")` would return "www.example").

Use [`ltrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) instead:

```
$base2 = ltrim($base,"www.");
```

Answer (score 0):

`chop`: http://php.net/manual/de/function.chop.php

I don't like replacing anywhere inside the string because you are asking to remove first characters only:

```
if (stripos($base,'www.') === 0)
{
   $base = substr($base, 4);
}
```

`stripos` to solve lower/upper cases.